# Multi-client capability und data storage

Tags: database, acl, evaluating-civicrm

One important question: Is your software solution able to deal with multi-clients, e.g. that data can be separated between different clients (companies) und security can be setup for this requirement? How is this requirement implemented in your software system? (Sites?)

And where is all your data being stored: in a database (e.g. Oracle)? und where is the database located? (Europe, States, .....)

Regrads, Jörg

Answer (score 2):

A big difference between CiviCRM and proprietary SAAS offerings is that you decide where to host the system, hence your second question is not applicable.

In terms of the first question, this is possible via 'multi-site' or other ACL approaches, but the question back to you is 'why not just have separate civicrm instances for each client?'.

You can also achieve a nice multi-site outcome using the [Related Permissions](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.relatedpermissions) extension that Fuzion created.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Some data will be accessed by both clients, e.g. one contact will be used by both clients. I guess, that this can be achieved by using multi-site or ACL .... hopefully I can do a testing :) is there any installation ready to do the testing?

Comment: CiviCRM is open source and you can download it for free from https://civicrm.org/download.  You can then test it to see if it meets your needs.